# Call static getter within a non static member function in es6 javascript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

How can i call a static function from a normal member function within an es 6 class?

Here is an example:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(text) {
        this.speech = text;
    }

    static get name() {
        return "Animal";
    }

    speak() {
        console.log( this.name + ":"+ this.speech)
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    static get name() {
        return "Tiger"
    }
}

var animal = new Animal("hey there");
animal.speak();
var tiger = new Tiger("hello");
tiger.speak();

// output: 
// undefined:hey there
// undefined:hello
```

I could change the speak function to return

```
speak() {
     console.log( Animal.name + ":"+ this.speech)
}
```

But this would always output the name from the Animal Class, but what i want is to output the static name property of the current class (e.g. "Tiger" within the subclass). How can i do that?

Comment: You could use `this.constructor.name`, at least in your case that would work (static members are properties of the constructor function and [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) is helping you there). However, i am unsure whether that is the best/cleanest solution.

Comment: Why is it static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a non static `get name()` to the `Animal` class that returns `this.constructor.name`:

```
get name() {
    return this.constructor.name;
}
```

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(text) {
        this.speech = text;
    }

    static get name() {
        return "Animal";
    }

    get name() {
        return this.constructor.name;
    }

    speak() {
        console.log( this.name + ":"+ this.speech)
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    static get name() {
        return "Tiger"
    }
}

var animal = new Animal("hey there");
animal.speak();
var tiger = new Tiger("hello");
tiger.speak();
```